# Primefaces Jquery error while using p:tree in p:dialog component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We are using primefaces 4.0 and have implemented tree component with checkboxes inside `p:dialog`. When I select the checkbox first time, it works fine i.e. it calls the p:ajax listener onNodeSelect method, but it throws the javascript error related to jquery and after that page stops responding. None of the button or checkbox works after first selection and here is the error related to jquery

```
Message: Syntax error
Line: 14
Char: 4928
Code: 0
URI: /cbp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=4.0&v=4.0
```

the xhtml code is as follows:

```
<p:dialog id="fdclist" header="FDC" widgetVar="dlg9" modal="true"
    height="600" width="800" showEffect="explode">
    <h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="panalGridNoBorder">

            <p:tree value="#{regRptMB.root}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox"
                selection="#{regRptMB.selectedNodes}" id="treeMultiple"
                style="height:500px; width:800px; overflow-y:auto;" dynamic="true">

                <p:treeNode>
                    <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                </p:treeNode>
                <p:ajax listener="#{regRptMB.onNodeSelect}" event="select"></p:ajax>
                <p:ajax listener="#{regRptMB.onNodeUnSelect}" event="unselect"></p:ajax>
            </p:tree>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:commandButton value="continue" action="#{regRptMB.getNodeNames}"
        oncomplete="dlg9.hide();" />

</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated ...